# Eclipse RCP - how to export eclipse RCP Preference pages to a database?

Tags: java, database, export, eclipse-rcp

What is the best way to export the eclipse/java preferences to the database programmatically?
How should the properties be  exported, by which interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think that exist such a functionality.

You can read the propertiwe following [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html)

Once you have the properties you need you can save them everywhere.

You also can use the exportWizard extension point to register your custom export wizard (org.eclipse.ui.IExportWizard)

you can take a look at PreferencesExportWizard class and WizardPreferencesExportPage1 class

Comment: Sorry, i mean programmatically

Comment: uops! ;) you can try reading this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html

Comment: I did, unfortunately there is nothing about export

Comment: there are no facilities to export properties directly to a database. I'm afraid that you have to write the code to read the properties you need an to save them on a DB. To do this you could register an export wizard.